# Append CSS onChange with Array Value(s)

Tags: jquery, css, arrays, append

I have an app that, when a color scheme is selected from a form dropdown, the hexidecimal values associated to that color scheme populate specific text fields from each field's array value (this part works). What I cannot get the app to do is change the background color of the text field to match that particular value.

I have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z4WxP/7/

I've tried (multiple variations of) adding a class and doing a css append to populate with the value to no avail, like so:

```
document.getElementsByName('color_body_bg')[0].value = bodyBG[text].css('background-color',value = bodyBG[text]);
```

Comment: So many problems with that JS... not worth a migraine headache today. Start with [object literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers) and not using an `Array` as an `Object`. Go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  document.getElementsByName('color_body_bg')[0].style.backgroundColor = bodyBG[text];
```

that's the basic code for it

http://jsfiddle.net/XqCQJ/

Comment: Excellent. Joseph and Tarek - both of your solutions worked. They were so simple that I'm facepalming and considering taking Homer's trademark 'D'oh' away from him. THANKS!

Comment: @farsider you're welcome. :)  And it happens to everybody.  Staring at the same piece of code for a long time can do that to you :P

Answer (score 1):

Add this to then end of `displayColor()`

```
  $('.appendSelection').each( function (){
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', $(this).val());
  });
```